# How to make the output of a snap "parts:" available to "apps:"?

Tags: yaml, snapcraft

```
apps:
  library-sample:
    command: library_sample

parts:
  library:
    source: https://github.com/the/sample.git
    plugin: cmake
```

When snapcraft runs the `cmake` install, "library" will be installed on the system (as I would expect). Also, `cmake` will also produce a test application in a `samples` folder under the `build` directory.

**I would like to promote the sample (generated by the "part") to be an installed app within the snap package.**

How do I use snap YAML to move from a nested directory under the `build` folder, into the snaps `/bin` folder?

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that the library makes it into the snap via an install rule, but there is no install rule for the samples?

Comment: Yes. The CMAKE install rule installs the library as it should. The sample is only a sample, and is not intended to be installed with the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by utilizing Snapcraft's [scriptlets](https://snapcraft.io/docs/build-snaps/scriptlets). Specifically, the `install` scriptlet. They essentially allow you to modify the behavior of the build process by customizing sections of it. In the `build` lifecycle step, snapcraft esentially runs `cmake && make && make install`, but `make install` doesn't do everything you want it to do. The `install` scriptlet runs right after `make install`, so you can do something like this:

```
parts:
  library:
    source: https://github.com/the/sample.git
    plugin: cmake
    install: |
      cp -r path/to/samples $SNAPCRAFT_PART_INSTALL/
```

Now clean the build step with `snapcraft clean -s build` and run `snapcraft` again. Then the samples directory will end up in the final snap.

Comment: After I run `snapcraft prime`, where would I look to see this file to confirm it worked as I expected?

Comment: To answer my own follow up, you would call `tree prime/` from the root of the snap (i.e. the same place you are probably calling `snapcraft`

Comment: Will you update your answer to remind people to call `snapcraft clean <part> -s build`? I will give you the check either way, but I would really appreciate it, as this was the true root of my problem.